# code gives "java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 14"

Tags: java, string, hadoop, mapreduce

the following code gives me **`"java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 14"`**

Please guide me on what is wrong with my code.

```
public class max_temp {

    public static class TokenizerMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

        private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
        private Text word = new Text();
        public String y;
        public String a;
        public Double t;

        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
            while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
                word.set(itr.nextToken());
                y = word.toString();
                a = y.substring(7,14);
                t = Double.parseDouble((y.substring(35,41).trim()));

                word.set(a);              

               // 27516201501012.424-156.6171.32-18.3-21.8-20.0-1   9.90.00.00C-19.2-24.5-21.983.973.777.                                
               context.write(word, one);
           }
       }
   }

   public static class IntSumReducer extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> {
       private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            int sum = 0;
            for (IntWritable val : values) {
                sum += val.get();
            }
            result.set(sum);
            context.write(key, result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The 15th character in your string does not exist. Your string is shorter than that.

Comment: does every word has 21 characters or more?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java substring : string index out of range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/953527/java-substring-string-index-out-of-range)

Comment: Did my answer help you? If yes, please mark it as a solution by clicking on the gray tick below the answer score.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you attached the stacktrace. Anyway, the problem is, that you're calling the `substring(7,14)` of the `String` which has length smaller then 15. Java doesn't know what to do and therefore throws an exception.

The problem is with your app logic. If you use `substring(7,14)` you have to be sure that the `String` is long enough or use `try-catch` block.

```
try {
    String s = s.substring(7,14);
} catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    //somehow process the situation in which the string is too short.
}
```