# How to Test if a String Index is Null in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm getting "java.lang.NullPointerException" when I run the following code:

```
    while(StringName[PlaceString] != null){
      StringCounter = 0;
        while(StringCounter < StringName[PlaceString].length()){
          System.out.println("PlaceString: " + PlaceString + " PlaceLine: " 
          + PlaceLine + " Length of string: " + StringName[PlaceString].length());
          //Does stuff with string
    }}
```

The output is:

```
    PlaceString: 0 PlaceLine: 0 Length of string: 2
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

The root of the error is:

```
    while(StringCounter < StringName[PlaceString].length()){
```

although it runs the next line that prints variable's values.  I can't figure out why it's complaining about a NullPointer when it can print their values.

Edit:
Since I'm not getting a java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException, the question:

[Java substring : string index out of range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953527/java-substring-string-index-out-of-range)

didn't help.

Comment: Looks like duplicate question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953527/java-substring-string-index-out-of-range. The answer explains how a utility function is recommended to fix the string null errors that are in your while condition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java substring : string index out of range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953527/java-substring-string-index-out-of-range)

Comment: Does "Does stuff with string" change the value of PlaceString or StringName anywhere?

Comment: Yes, I do increment all of the counter variables by one using "++"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't show all the relevant code but according to the exception and its location, you set very probably the value of `PlaceString` during the inner `while` :

```
while(StringCounter < StringName[PlaceString].length()){
      System.out.println("PlaceString: " + PlaceString + " PlaceLine: " 
      + PlaceLine + " Length of string: " + StringName[PlaceString].length());
      //Does stuff with string
       StringCounter++; // or something close
}
```

At a certain iteration, `StringName[PlaceString]` refers to a `null` element.
So the NPE is thrown.

The  outer `while` will not help here :

```
while(StringName[PlaceString] != null){
```

as it is not executed before the inner loop terminates its iterations.

So you could avoid the NPE by adding the guard in the inner `while` :

```
while(StringName[PlaceString] != null && StringCounter < StringName[PlaceString].length()){
      System.out.println("PlaceString: " + PlaceString + " PlaceLine: " 
      + PlaceLine + " Length of string: " + StringName[PlaceString].length());
      //Does stuff with string
}
```